# Appium Testing for iOS App

Tags: ios, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I am getting these errors while trying to test iOS app using Appium. Can anyone guide me where I am going wrong?

1)

```
debug: Starting Appium in pre-launch mode

error: Could not determine your device from Appium arguments or desired capabilities. Please make sure to specify the 'deviceName' capability
debug: Got configuration error, not starting session
debug: Cleaning up appium session
error: Could not pre-launch appium: Error: Could not determine your device from Appium arguments or desired capabilities. Please make sure to specify the 'deviceName' capability

info: Pre-launching app
```

2)

```
Could Not Launch Appium Inspector

Could not get list of sessions from Appium Server

Be sure the Appium server is running with an application opened by using the "App Path" parameter in Appium.app (along with package and activity for Android) or by connecting with selenium client and supplying this in the desired capabilities object.
```

Answer (score 0):

From the second entry I'm assuming you're trying to launch the inspector from within appium.

I got around this is by going into the iOS Settings and selecting Force Device.  After that the inspector started up nicely.

[image]